# Does this series diverge or converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does this serie diverge or converge ? Why ?

$$\sum \frac{\sqrt{n^3}+e^{-n}}{\sqrt{n^5}+\pi}$$

Comment: Remark: the singular is series; I've edited the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

The key fact is that

$$ \frac{\sqrt{n^3}+e^{-n}}{\sqrt{n^5}+\pi}\sim \frac1n$$

then refer to limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1n$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I prove that 1/n always has a lower value ?

Comment: @Anton What do you mean by "a lower value"?

Comment: You don't want the $\sum$ sign there.

Comment: @zhw. Opsss..thanks I fix that!

Comment: That was a wrong question. I've just garbled a limit comparison test with a direct comparison test. Now I get you. So I've got 1 after taking a limit of       "my series"   /   "1/n". Does it mean that my series diverges? Thanks for help

Comment: @Anton Yes refer to [LCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Comment: @gimusi Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Anton Refer also to the following [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986815/505767) and to my answer for the application in 0 and $\infty$ cases not covered in the wiki reference